# Dynamically add dimensions to boolean array

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I'm using flutter to develop an e-commerce app.
I'm working on the navDrawer for it and I could use some help with the categories.
I have categories that can have subcategories and the subcategories can also have their own subcategories.
Basically, the data set is an array of unknown dimensions.

I need to make a boolean map for my categories and subcategories so that I can keep track of which ones are open in order to show the subcategories.

Here's an example of the dataset:

```
{
      "id":"41490",
      "name":"Electrical Equipment",
      "subCategories":[
         {
            "id":"41492",
            "name":"Breakers",
            "subCategories":[
               {
                  "id":"167542",
                  "name":"1 Pole",
                  "subCategories":[
                     {
                        "id":"167577",
                        "name":"15 Amp",
                        "subCategories":null
                     },
                     {
                        "id":"167585",
                        "name":"20 Amp",
                        "subCategories":null
                     },
                     {
                        "id":"167600",
                        "name":"30 Amp",
                        "subCategories":null
                     },
                     {
                        "id":"167606",
                        "name":"40 Amp",
                        "subCategories":null
                     }
                  ]
               },
```

I think recursion is the optimal way to process this dataset but the problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to have dynamic dimensions for an array in Dart.
I already figured out how to generate my listTiles from the dataset but I can't figure out the boolean map.
Is this even possible or should I look into a different approach?

Here's my code for generating the listTiles from the dataset:

```
  void setCategories(List categories){
      _categories = categories;
      int catCount = categories.length;
      _categoryList = new ListView.builder(
          //shrinkWrap: true,
          //physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          padding:EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          itemCount: catCount,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => buildCategories(context, index),
      );
  }
  Widget buildCategories(BuildContext context, int index){
    if(_categories[index]['subCategories']!=null){
      //TODO: call buildSubCategories with depth of 1 parameter
      return Container(
          height: 30.0,
          child: ListTile(
              title: Row(
                children:[
                  Text("        "+_categories[index]['name']),
                  Transform.scale(
                      scale: 0.75,
                      child:
                      Icon(Icons.arrow_back)
                  )
                ]
              ),
              onTap: () {
                  //TODO: implement boolean map here
              }
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(0.0)
      );
    } else {
      return Container(
          height: 30.0,
          child: ListTile(
              title: Text("        "+_categories[index]['name']),
              onTap: () {

              }
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(0.0)
      );
    }
  }

  Widget buildSubCategories(var parent, int depth){
      List subCategoryList = parent['subCategories'];
      int subCategoryCount = subCategoryList.length;
      if(parent['subCategories']!=null){
          //for each subCategory
          //if subCategory has subCategories
          //recurse subCategory with depth

          buildSubCategories(parent['subCategories'], depth++);
          //TODO: implement boolean map here
      } else {
          //
      }
  }

  void generateCategoryBooleanMap(){
      //TODO: generate boolean map here
      //TODO: boolean map needs to have a undetermined amount of depth levels
  }
```

Any insight is appreciated even if it means I have to use a different paradigm.

Comment: Is the `id` unique in your data? Because if that is the case you could also just make a simple `Set<String>`. You could then make it so if the `id` is in the `Set` it means `true` and if the `id` is missing, it means false.

Comment: All the IDs are unique and every item has an ID. I'm not too sure what you mean?

Comment: Added a solution with an example of what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of using a `Set` to keep track of which `id` is open:

```
void main() {
  final idHandler = IdHandler();

  print(idHandler.isIdOpen('MyId')); // false
  idHandler.openId('MyId');
  
  print(idHandler.isIdOpen('MyId')); // true
  idHandler.closeId('MyId');
  
  print(idHandler.isIdOpen('MyId')); // false
  idHandler.openId('MyId');
  
  print(idHandler.isIdOpen('MyId')); // true
  idHandler.closeAll();
  
  print(idHandler.isIdOpen('MyId')); // false
}

class IdHandler {
  final Set<String> _openIds = {};

  void openId(String id) => _openIds.add(id);
  void closeId(String id) => _openIds.remove(id);
  void closeAll() => _openIds.clear();
  bool isIdOpen(String id) => _openIds.contains(id);
}
```

Comment: Ok I have to wrap my head around this and how to implement it in my code. That might actually work.

Comment: @TTR If it does not work, we can properly figure out some more feasible solution. This was just the simplest solution I could came up with :)

Comment: Alright I appreciate the help! I'll let you know once I get some code done.

Comment: Using Hashing for this is a very elegant solution and removes the need to iterate all the categories. While it doesn't answer my specific question (because I did mention that I was open to different paradigms), it does solve my problem so I am going to mark this as the answer.
If I could I'd give you bonus points for giving me an efficient answer!